# How to prevent screen brightness change when I move my mouse up?

Tags: 14.04, mouse, screen, brightness, cursor

When I quickly move the mouse cursor up to the top of the screen, its brightness increases. How can I prevent this? I use Ubuntu 14.04. Maybe it depends on laptop? Mine one is Lenovo E450. If yes, what do I do in that case?

Comment: LOL, never heard or noticed that before. Does it also decrease when you move the mouse downwards?

Comment: Is that a bug or a feature?

Comment: Sorry, no offence. But that behaviour really sounds hilarious. Do you mean "moving the mouse"? or something else, like a touchpad or cursor keys? Perhaps you have installed some gesture software. I don't know if such exists, but that would be a possible explanation.

Comment: Did you activate something like "adaptive screen brightness"? Does the brightness also change when you move the cursor slowly?

Comment: @danzel Even If I did this, it was accidentaly because I don't know how to do this:) No, it doesn't change if I move slowly